# Espresso - use a grid view inside of a view pager containing other grid views

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to select an item from a grid view that is located in a view pager.

The different pages in the view pager contain identical grid views (but with different content).

Is there a way to handle this somehow?

I have the following logic:

```
onData(new BaseMatcher<String>() {
    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        // what?
        description.appendText("Matches A");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        return item instanceof String && ((String) item).equals("A");
    }
}).inAdapterView(allOf(withId(R.id.grid_view))).perform(click());
```

Which I was hoping to start with/work on (the base matcher needs to have the matches method updated, but I can work on that next...).

However, the call fails due to:

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '(with id: com.zachproject.espresso:id/grid_view)' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.
```

Which makes sense since multiple grid_view ids are found (one per page in the view pager).

Any ideas to make this work?

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `isDisplayed()` to your adapter matcher, it will only match the `AdapterView` that is being displayed on the screen, which will be the `AdapterView` on the current page in most cases.

`allOf(withId(R.id.grid_view), isDisplayed())`

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I didn't try that...

Here's what I have:

`onData(CustomerMatchers.withTitle(title)).inAdapterView(allOf(withId(R.id.grid_view), isDisplayed())).perform(click());`